# Importing CSV files to Excel 2003 with more than 256 columns

Tags: arrays, vba, csv, import

I like to import some csv files with 375 columns into excel 2003. But excel 2003 limits the number of columns to 256.

*I  must edit this question due to relevancy*

I have several CSV-files with exactly 375 columns and different number of rows. How can I delete every second (odd) column which contains unnecessary information. The unneeded columns are from number 5 to 375 (5, 7, 9, ...373, 375).
Is there a useful solution to delete all unneeded columns with a script in **VBS**?

I will keep my fingers cross  to get a solution and thank you in advance.

Mike

Comment: I don't know what limits are with SSIS but could you try setting up a package (if you have access to software) that performs this task? Are the columns in either the same order or have the same names each time?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with SSiS, it is too expensive and I have no access.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with SSiS, it is too expensive and I have no access.
The columns in each file are always in the same order.
Each column which must be removed, begins with HD02 and contains the word 'Percent' in the second line of the header.
I like to remove every 2nd column start with culumn 5 (7, 9, 11, ....)
Header Line#1**,**Header Lin#2
GEO.id**,**Id
GEO.id2**,**Id2
GEO.display-label**,**Geography
HD01_S001**,**Number; SEX AND AGE <5..
HD02_S001**,**Percent; SEX AND AGE <5 
HD01_S002**,**Number; SEX AND AGE 5-9
HD02_S002**,**Percent; SEX AND AGE 5-9
HD01_S003...

Comment: Please edit additional information into the question. Many people won't bother to read all the comments especially if they contain an eye punishing mess (generally what happens when trying to put a̶ ̶s̶m̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶a̶m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶ ̶ more than the tiniest bit of code into the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the CSV Editors. They will generally allow you to delete columns. You will have to specify which columns to delete (i.e. you will not be able to delete columns via the content). But you should be able to delete enough to view / edit in Excel. Also you could 
cut/paste from the Csv Editor into Excel as well.

Here are several (first 2 are free, the next 2 have a 30 day trial)

http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/
http://recsveditor.sourceforge.net/

http://www.whitepeaksoftware.com/killink-csv-editor/

http://www.gammadyne.com/csv_editor_pro.htm

You could also google "CSV editor" / check SourceForge for more

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the reply and the links. I don't need a CSV Editor because they are **not able to delete columns via the content** _(as you said)_. I still use **CSVed** and I think it is a good editor, but can only **delete columns by viewing and checking them**.
I need more automatization as I have to work with many files with different "column lengths". So I can not view each file seperately.

Answer (score 0):

**After a long time and no response...**
I tried several CSV-editors (free or purchasable), but nobody seems to have the options to delete columns by having the string "percent" in their header). Only **ReCsvEditor_0.80.6** is working with filters, but the filter seems not to work properly.

**If anyone have a suitable VBS (WSH) script solution I would be very grateful.**